# K-Means plot resulting unreal points in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to plot a K-Means cluster to analyze different categories of products based on their inventory average and sold quantity.

All values are non-negative and of the same measurement unit. 
I don't know what I did wrong and the results contain point with negative values. Actually, I believe all the points given in the plot aren't actual valid points from my data.

[image: Cluster of categories for sold quantity and inventory]

Here is my code:

```
reduced_dataset = dataset[1:20, 4:5]

# Using the elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters
wcss = vector()
for (i in 1:10) wcss[i] = sum(kmeans(reduced_dataset, i)$withinss)
plot(1:10,
 wcss,
 type = 'b',
 main = paste('The Elbow Method'),
 xlab = 'Number of clusters',
 ylab = 'WCSS')

# As a result, number of clusters should be 2

# Fitting K-Means to the dataset
kmeans = kmeans(x = reduced_dataset, centers = 2)
y_kmeans = kmeans$cluster

# Visualising the clusters
library(cluster)
clusplot(reduced_dataset,
     y_kmeans,
     lines = 0,
     shade = TRUE,
     color = TRUE,
     labels = 2,
     plotchar = FALSE,
     span = TRUE,
     main = paste('Clusters of categories - NOT ON SALE'),
     xlab = 'Average Sold Quantity',
     ylab = 'Average Inventory')

dput(reduced_dataset):

structure(list(Avg_Sold_No_Promo = c(0.255722695, 1.139983236, 
0.458651842, 0.784966698, 1.642746914, 0.115264798, 7.50338696, 
0.487603306, 1.023373984, 0.956099815, 1.505901506, 0.253837072, 
0.834963325, 0.880898876, 6.527699531, 11.54054054, 3.44077135, 
0.750182882, 0.251033058, 1.875698324), Avg_Inventory_No_Promo = 
c(6.068672335, 
22.57865326, 9.00694927, 11.56137012, 28.47530864, 7.485981308, 
170.9064352, 11.07438017, 22.80792683, 40.63863216, 41.73463573, 
10.87603306, 35.87408313, 46.09213483, 185.5671362, 315.6015693, 
165.1129477, 78.18032187, 9.65857438, 198.4385475)), .Names = 
c("Avg_Sold_No_Promo", 
"Avg_Inventory_No_Promo"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: It'll be hard, since we cannot reproduce the behavior. It looks like the data is a bit larger than we typically deal with here on SO, so can you reduce `dataset` to perhaps 10-20 data points and still reproduce the problem? If yes, then please edit your question with the output of `dput(reduced_dataset)`.

Comment: See the documentation for `clusplot` -- it uses principal components or multidemensional scaling to represent the axes.

Comment: You still need to use `dput` for anyone to help, but I'm guessing `plot(reduced_dataset[[1]], reduced_dataset[[2]], col = c(1:4)[y_kmeans])` will probably get what you're after.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns, thank you very much! It worked!

Comment: Also, thanks @r2evans for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clusplot` function does this automatically.

It is called PCA, and that is also why you get the line with the variability explained there.